# Primefaces picklist labels are empty after update

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Form with picklist:

```
<p:inputText id="number" value="#{accountNumberBean.account.accountNumber}" required="true" label="#{msg['newAccountNumberForm.number']}">
    <f:validateLength maximum="50" for="name" />
</p:inputText>

<p:message for="number" display="text" />

<p:pickList id="integrations" value="#{accountNumberBean.integrations}" var="integration" itemLabel="#{integration.name} (#{integration.backend.name})" itemValue="#{integration}" converter="integrationConverter">
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">#{msg['newAccountNumberForm.integrations.available']}/>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">#{msg['newAccountNumberForm.integrations.used']}/>
</p:pickList>
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['button.createAndNext']}" action="#{accountNumberBean.addNewAndStay}" update="@form" />
```

When i dont fill the number input a click the command button - validation message is shown, but labels of object in picklist updates and they are only empty brackets.

```
itemLabel="#{integration.name} (#{integration.backend.name})"
```

When i select them and fill the name - everything is ok (works as if i filled the name in the first place), so only problem are the labels.
This is my converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Integration.class, value = "integrationConverter")
public class IntegrationConverter implements Converter {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} 
     */
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Integration integration = new Integration();
        integration.setId(Long.parseLong(value));
        return integration;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} 
     */
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return ((Integration) value).getId().toString();
    }

}
```

And method on the bean to get integrations (bean is view scoped):

```
public DualListModel<Integration> getIntegrations() {
        integrations.setSource(customerService.getIntegrations(customer));
        return integrations;
    }
```

What is causing that labels are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your converter you are only passing the id value of your pojo so when it gets converted it's basically a null object with a setted id.

Changing your converter to below will most likely make the first label properly shown:

```
 /**
 * {@inheritDoc} 
 */
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Integration integration = new Integration();
    String[] split = value.split("_");
    integration.setId(split[0]);
    integration.setName(split[1]);
    return integration;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc} 
 */
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    Integration i = (Integration) value;
    return i.getId() + "_" + i.getName();
}
```

However, if your class is a persistent entity you might want to retrieve the object from the database in your converter, check the following code:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Object object = null;

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
        try {
            int underscoreIndex = value.indexOf("_");
            String className = value.substring(0, underscoreIndex);
            String id = value.substring(underscoreIndex + 1, value.length());

            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
            object = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(clazz, Long.parseLong(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return object;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String result = null;

    if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
            Integration obj = (Integration) value;
            result = Hibernate.getClass(obj).getName() + "_" + obj.getId();
        }
    return result;
}

private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        sessionFactory = ((SessionFactory) FacesContextUtils                    .getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())
                .getBean("sessionFactory"));
    }

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

I am assuming you are using hibernate and spring, and the sessionFactory bean is defined in your application context.

Comment: While you're right about the cause of OP's problems 1)Why're you assuming he's using hibernate and spring? 2) Your solution will throw an NPE should a null value be supplied to the converter

Comment: The purpose of the first solution was to make it easier for the op to understand the cause of the problem, it also doesn't set the name for the backend property of the Integration pojo as well, but I think it exemplifies the solution well enough.
I chose hibernate and spring because they make good abstractions to get my point across, I didn't want to spam a wall of boilerplate code just to make a connection to database.

Comment: Thank you, getting Integration from database solved my problem. But my code does not have to be this complex. I am using spring and i have dao object for Integration. If i anotate converter with `@Component("integrationConverter")` instead of @FacesConverter (and use it as `converter="#{integrationConverter}"`) i can autowire that dao and get entities from the database easily.

Comment: Yes that looks cleaner, I got the db integration code from an old project of mine where the converters were supposed to be FacesConverters as a standart, anyway glad to be of help.